# Using UISearchbar on Struct

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct, uisearchbar

I have two `UITableViewControllers` in my project. The first is just a simple `tableView` that displays an ordinary `array`. The second `tableView` is populated by a `Struct`
I have implemented a `UISearcBar`in the first `ViewController` without any trouble. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Search-Bar-Guide) Here is the code I use for the searchbar in the first `viewController`:

```
let listArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"]
var searchData: [String]!        

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchData = listArray
    }     

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }    

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        searchData = searchText.isEmpty ? listArray : listArray { (item: String) -> Bool in
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In the second `ViewController` I use a `Struct` to populate the `tableView`
When I try to implement the searchBar it gives an error:

```
 struct ObjectModel {

        var objectProducer: String?
        var objecType: String?
        var unit: String?
        var contentSize: Double?
        var amount: Double?
        var addedDate: String?

    }    

     var objectList = [ObjectModel]()
        //Search data
      var filteredData = [ObjectModel]()    


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
       //SearchData
            searchBar.delegate = self
            filteredData = objectList  //   
          }        

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return filteredData.count
        }    

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! ListCell

            //the artist object
                   let object: ObjectModel

                   object = objectList[indexPath.row]

if activeSearch = false {    

              cell.objectNameLabel.text = "\(object.objectProducer ?? "Missing data"), \(object.objecType ?? "Missing data")"    
} else {
            cell.objectNameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.row] //Error: Cannot assign value of type 'ObjectModel' to type 'String?'    
}

            return cell

        }   


          func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

              filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? objectList : objectList.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in //Error: 'String' is not convertible to 'ObjectModel'
                  return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
              }

              tableView.reloadData()
          }
```

How should I implement a search when I use `Struct`?

Comment: what's the error? and where is the line `tableView.delegate = self`line?

Comment: @elia there are two errors. First in `cellForRowAt` //Error: Cannot assign value of type 'ObjectModel' to type 'String?' . Second is in the searchBar Function: //Error: 'String' is not convertible to 'ObjectModel'  The errors is showed in the original code above.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: @elia I'm sorry. I haven't had the time to test it before now. Please see comment on your answer

Comment: change `objectList.filter { (item: String) -> Bool` in to `objectList.filter { (item: ObjectModel) -> Bool` in because the items in the list are `ObjectModel` type. Then you can handle the remain parts. And check my answer edit line, you must `reloadData` of your `tableView` in main thread.

Comment: @elia Perfect! Thanks

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: @elia Yes! I think so. I have only had the time to test it briefly, but it seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
cell.objectNameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
```

to

```
   cell.objectNameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].objectProducer
```

Because in `ObjectModel` struct, you have to assign one of the property has to be assigned `text` variable of the `UILabel`. You can assign

```
    var objectProducer: String?
    var objecType: String?
    var unit: String?
    var contentSize: Double?
    var amount: Double?
    var addedDate: String?
```

properties `String` description. For example if you want to assign amount you can use

```
cell.objectNameLabel.text = "\(filteredData[indexPath.row].amount!)"
```

Or there is better way.

You must extend your `ObjectModel` with `CustomStringConvertible` so your all struct variable can described as string then it can worked like that

```
cell.objectNameLabel.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
```

You can extend it like below.

```
extension ObjectModel: CustomStringConvertible{

  public var description: String { 
    return "amount \(self.amount) producer \(self.producer) bla bla"
  }

}
```

// edit

change to it with main thread.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

to :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 


   self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Progress! But still get an error in the `func searchBar` In the line ` filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? objectList : objectList.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in` I get the error  `'String' is not convertible to 'ObjectModel'`